# Is there a way to indicate/show "runas" user or administrative rights in the titlebar of a window in windows7?

Tags: windows-7, uac, window-manager, user-interface

I sometimes start applications with elevated rights and forget to close them later because they are not distinguishable. Through something like an "Open File..." someone can easily abuse those apps if my normal account is "compromised".

The question is if there is a way to indicate that a window is created by application with elevated rights.

I noticed that the windows are handled differently internally and access control is enforced: e.g. that extensions like dexpot cannot hook to those windows.

Answer (score 1):

Given the lengths that was required to get something like that to work for IE/Explorer ( [see Privbar](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203063153/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/195350.aspx)) , I do not think there is a solution that will affect all programs.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of is [code to check for administrative permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff420334.aspx).
Maybe someone could write a tool that draws a red border around elevated windows...

Maybe something similar should be suggested to Microsoft to be included in one of the next releases..

Answer (score 0):

A command prompt run as administrator adds `Administrator` to the title bar, but this seems to be the only case of this built in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to parse username into tile windows.

You can test this in batch files:
title %USERNAME%
will add the user name to the title window.

I assume something equivalent for non-cmd/batch windows can be done via VBS.
Anyway, it's env variables you should use.